# fancybox jquery on templete field of gridview binding issue

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Here I have created a website in c#.net and I want the page which will be open after clicking the gridview field in the fancybox.
But I am facing one problem that it opens the page in fancybox for the first row only I don't know why..?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.easing-1.3.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.css"
    media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#deal_VCU').fancybox({
                'width': '85%',
                'height': '85%',
                'autoScale': false,
                'transitionIn': 'none',
                'transitionOut': 'none',
                'type': 'iframe',
                'titleShow': false
            });
        });
 </script>

<asp:GridView ID="GrdDeals" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="1" DataKeyNames="OFID" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource3"
    ForeColor="#333333" GridLines="None" PageSize="100" 
    onrowdatabound="GrdDeals_RowDataBound" onrowcommand="GrdDeals_RowCommand">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="OFID" HeaderText="Offer ID" SortExpression="OFID" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Text_Message" HeaderText="Offer Text" SortExpression="Text_Message" />

        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deal for VCU" SortExpression="Counter1">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="deal_VCU" href="DetailView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("OFID")%>&Op1=Counter2">
                    <%#Eval("Counter2")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deal for SCSU" SortExpression="Counter2">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="deal_SCSU" href="DetailView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("OFID")%>&Op1=Counter2">
                    <%#Eval("Counter2")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Deal for Trinity" SortExpression="Counter3">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <a id="deal_Trinity" href="DetailView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("OFID")%>&Op1=Counter3">
                    <%#Eval("Counter3")%></a>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <FooterStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <RowStyle BackColor="#EFF3FB" Height="4" />
    <EditRowStyle BackColor="#2461BF" />
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#D1DDF1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#333333" />
    <PagerStyle BackColor="#2461BF" ForeColor="White" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#507CD1" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Here I am facing one problem that the fancybox is getting open for the first row only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because since there are multiple hyperlink controls are there with the same `ID`. Please assign a css class (say `deal_VCUCSS` )

```
 <a id="deal_VCU" class="deal_VCUCSS" href="DetailView.aspx?ID=<%#Eval("OFID")%>&Op1=Counter2">
                                <%#Eval("Counter2")%></a>
```

and use the below

```
 $('.deal_VCUCSS').fancybox({
```

Comment: Can you please check if you added the class as I have put it in the updated code above?

Comment: What will be there inside the class..? can you please specify that.?

Comment: it doesn't matter. We use it as a selector for the jquery.

Comment: I am not getting you...can you please elaborate..?

Comment: @KrunalMevada read this: http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/ . It basically is the same as your ID selector, but selects elements based on css class (as there should only be one element per id).

Comment: you can have a blank css class like .deal_VCUCSS{}
we use this for selecting the items with the class name deal_VCUCSS

Answer (score 1):

In order for the jQuery selector to work they need to know what element you are referring to, and since your code has an error (based on W3C an ID should be used only once in a html file in order for the DOM element to know what element you want to access).

You need to have a class, like in the previous comment in order to have the event listener. Or if you want to have different ID's for each link then you can loop and apply an event listener to all of them
$("#main_div_container").find("a").each(function(){ your code here;});
I hope that helps.